# FPGA LUT with multiple outputs

Tags: vhdl, fpga, rom

I am working on designing a Mandelbrot viewer and I am designing hardware for squaring values. My squarer is recursively built where a 4bit squarer relies on 2, 2bit squarers. so for my 16 bit squarer, that has 2 8bits squarers, and each one of those has 2 4bit squarer's.

As you can see the recursivity begins to make the design blow up in complexity. To help speed up my design I would like to use a 4input ROM that emulates a 4bit squarer. So when you enter 3 in the ROM, it outputs 9, when you enter 15, it outputs 225.

I know that a normal LUT implemented in a logic cell array to have 3 or 4 input variables and only 1 output, but I need an 8 bit output so I need more of a ROM than a LUT.

Any and all help is appreciated, I'm curious how the FPGA will store those ROMs and if storing it in ROM would be faster than computing the 4input Square.

Comment: I'm curious how you decompose one N-bit squarer into (only) two N/2-bit squarers.  You certainly need at least one more multiplier and a number of adders.  Can you share your algorithm?

Comment: yes it uses 1 multiplier that is also half the total of inputs bits, so an 8bit squarer requires 2 4bit squarers and 1 4 bit multiplier :)

Comment: an LUT can have a multi bit output, its basically a table. You could use a ROM as well, where for each element ROM[i], the value in memory is i^2. I think both options are viable. It will probably be faster than a computation because there are only 2^4 values in the table and the LUT or ROM will be inferred on chip (local)

Comment: `a 4bit squarer relies on [two] 2bit squarers` a weird approach given at least 4LUTs.

Comment: Rather than using an k/2 bit multiplier use two k/2+1 bit squarers, a subtractor and a couple of adders.

Answer (score 1):

To square a 4-bit number explicitly using LUTs, you would need to use 8 4-input LUTs.  Each LUT's output would give you one bit of the 8-bit product.

The overall size and f<sub>max</sub> performance of your design may be achieved with this approach, using larger block RAM primitives (as ROM), dedicated MAC (multiply-accumulate) units, or by using the normal multiplication operator `*` and relying on your synthesis tool's optimization.

You may also want to review some research papers related to this topic, for example [Saurabh Durgaprasad Gupta: A Fixed‑point Digit Serial Squaring Algorithm
Using an Arbitrary Number System](https://s2.smu.edu/%7Emitch/ftp_dir/pubs/Gupta-MS-thesis.pdf).

Comment: `you would need to use 8 4-input LUTs` for the combinatorics, 6 4LUTs will do nicely, as the result LSB is just the input LSB, and the next bit is a constant 0. Only 2 bits require 4LUTs/depend on all 4 bits, two on just 3, the remaining two on just 2 input bits.